# FaceTime on my MacBook

Tags: security, facetime, privacy

I just noticed that my camera light was on on my MacBook. I looked down at my dashboard and it said 9 users were on my FaceTime. I freaked and shut it down. Now is there anyway I can find out who was watching and how they turned it on?

Comment: Could it be that you just had the FaceTime app open (which turns the camera light on because it is using the camera) and noticed the recents list? The green light doesn't mean that it is on a call, it merely means that an app is using your camera (in this case that would be the FaceTime app).

Comment: I have never used it though

Answer (score 1):

Facetime is a 1:1 system. So, you can only be connected to 1 person. It's more likely the app had gotten run as bassplayer7 suggested and the green light just indicated that your camera was in use by an application. The 9 may have referred to the number of people in your address book you can Facetime with or that there are 9 recents in the recents list.